# Creating a torrent from a command line application (Windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, bittorrent

Does anyone know of a application that allows you to create torrent files via the command-line in Windows?

Update: I need a command-line version because I'm a programmer. I need to create the torrent programmatically, I can't have a window pop-up. There's a ton of uses for command-line torrent creation and I think it's very strange that I havent found a command line version from my hours of searching the Internet.

Comment: Why would you want to? Is there a problem that GUI based solutions don't solve?

Answer (score 7):

Alternative 1) [**mktorrent for Windows**](http://mktorrent.sourceforge.net/):

> Mktorrent is a very easy tool for
>   creating Torrents on the commandline,
>   but only for Linux (only Sourcecode to
>   compile self) – so i compiled a
>   Win32/Win64 Version over Cygwin.
>
> **Installation:** Copy the mktorrent.exe and the DLLs in
>   \Windows\System32\
>   On Server 2008 R2
>   Copy the mktorrent.exe in
>   \Windows\System32\ , and the DLLs in
>   \Windows\SysWOW64\
>
> **Usage i.e.:** mktorrent -l 21 -a http://tracker.url foldername

Alternative 2) [**py3createtorrent**](https://py3createtorrent.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user.html):

> py3createtorrent is a comprehensive
>   shell/commandline utility for creating
>   torrents (Linux & Windows). It's a
>   GPL-licensed Python v3.1 script. I
>   tested it with Ubuntu 8.04 / rTorrent
>   and Windows 7 / µTorrent.

Comment: The mktorrent link no longer works. Is there a build of mktorrent for Windows available somewhere else?

Comment: You're right, the link is rotten. As far as I remember, it can be run on Windows under MinGW/Cygwin.

Comment: I believe it's at https://github.com/Rudde/mktorrent . I've also come across another version of mktorrent compiled for Windows, but I haven't tested it. It's available at https://github.com/q3aql/mktorrent-win

Answer (score 1):

[Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) comes with `transmission-create` which is a command-line utility to create `.torrent` files.

```
Usage: transmission-create [options] <file|directory>

Options:
 -h --help              Display this help page and exit
 -p --private           Allow this torrent to only be used with the specified
                        tracker(s)
 -o --outfile <file>    Save the generated .torrent to this filename
 -c --comment <comment> Add a comment
 -t --tracker <url>     Add a tracker's announce URL
 -V --version           Show version number and exit
```

[Instructions for building Transmission on Windows.](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Building#OnWindows)

Comment: Transmission doesn't seem to be available for Windows.

Comment: I don't see any binaries available, but it can probably be compiled under Windows (Cygwin).

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install py3createtorrent
```

I wrote a Python script that asks for the path, then it runs the command. Simple to use.

```
from subprocess import run

filepath = input("To create a torrent, enter the full file path:\n").strip()
# Put double quotes around the path if needed
filepath = f'"{filepath}"' if '"' not in filepath else filepath
tracker = "" # fill this in
output_folder = "" # fill this in
# Creates a torrent with a Private flag and 8 mb piece size
command = f'py3createtorrent -P -p 8192 -t {tracker} {filepath} -o {output_folder}'
run(command, shell=True, capture_output=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

`mktorrent` mentioned by *Mehper C. Palavuzlar* will do the job.
Sample usage is

```
    mktorrent.exe -l %piece_size% -a %tracker_announce_url% %folder_or_file%
```

Piece size is power of 2, i.e. `-l 22` will create a torrent file with pieces of 2^22 bytes = 4 MB.

`mktorrent` is currently maintained by **Rudde**:
https://github.com/Rudde/mktorrent

To build it on Windows from sources you'll need `GNU Make` which you can get from [MinGW-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/), for example.

To build `mktorrent` for Windows 32-bit (provided you have `make` in your Windows' `PATH` environment variable and that current working directory is of `mktorrent` source code files):

```
    make CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc USE_LONG_OPTIONS=1 USE_LARGE_FILES=1
```

To build `mktorrent` for Windows 64-bit:

```
    make CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc USE_LONG_OPTIONS=1 USE_LARGE_FILES=1
```

`mktorrent.exe` and `prefix.exe` will be built.

Comment: mktorrent builds for Windows (with Cygwin) https://gitlab.com/q3aql/mktorrent-win-builds/

Answer (score 0):

A new and fast option is [torrenttools](https://github.com/fbdtemme/torrenttools):

- Support for the new v2 and hybrid protocols
- Fast multi-buffer hashing with Intel ISA-L

Documentation: https://fbdtemme.github.io/torrenttools/commands/create.html

[image]